# retrieve data from other sites using XPath

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I am trying to retrieve data from other sites using HTML Agilitypack with the help of Xpath. I have successfully added data from one site but when i change the URL and XPath to retrieve data from another site, it does not work.

Here is my working code:

```
string Url = "http://www.uok.edu.pk/faculties/computerscience/bs.php";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();    
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);    
var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
"//*[@id=\"courses_sec\"]/div[2] /div[2]/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td");
```

But i change the XPath and URL, the variable `headers` is null. This is the code which is not working:

```
string Url = "http://music.dodear.com/index.php";    
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();    
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);    
var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
"//*[@id=\"content\"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/
table[1]/tbody/tr/td");
```

Comment: It would help if you explained *what data* you want to retrieve, exactly. And more generally, do not let tools write XPath for you. You will always end up with a hideous mess that breaks easily at the slightest change in site structure. Write your XPath yourself.

Comment: I want to retrieve list of thata that has two Columns one is Name of University (Under which about 64 names exists) and the other column name is location.The same is working for above code but not working for code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the XPath is wrong, or the HTML has some sort of bad format (tags that don't close, etc) that may necessitate some complex XPath to access. Why don't you break down the XPath piece-by-piece? For example, once you get the web.Load(Url) to load to the HtmlDocument, you can do a Watch on

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"content\"]").InnerHtml;
```

then

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div[2]").InnerHtml;
```

then

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//[@id=\"content\"]/div[2]/table").InnerHtml;
```

etc.

So you can figure out what the problem is

Comment: //[@id=\"content\"]/div[2]" At this point it gives some values but when i add "/table/..." then it gives null . Plz help this is very difficult to understand the actual problem here

Comment: Any software exists  that work for me so that i gaive url and Xpath and it give me result ??????????